# $sce.trustAsHtml is not evaluating a javascript string (or trustAsJs For that matter);

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My server has a json endpoint that returns a html/js string, looks similar to such:

```
"\r\n\r\n<div id=\'myEditor\" name=\"myEditor\">\r\n\r\n\t\t<a href=\"http://example.com\"></a>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/MyEditor/WebResource.axd?...\:">\r\n\r\n\t<script>\r\n\t..."
```

I want to inject this with angular into a div, and have it execute the javascript as well.

First attempt:

```
function myCtrl ($sce) {
  $http.get(endpoint).then(function (response) { 
    $scope.html = response.data;
    $scope.editorHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html); //also tried trustAsJs
   }
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="editorHtml"></div>
```

I noticed that if I return a pure html string those tags get rendered, however a pure javascript tags do NOT get evaluated. How do I get it to evaulate these tags? AngularJS version 1.5.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `HTML` has some syntax problem such **id=\'myEditor\"**. I replaced it with **id=\'myEditor\'** and so ...

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yshadmehr/rjyhe4h7/)
Add [angular.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js) and [angular-sanitize.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js) to your project. I used [jquery 2.2.4](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) for this sample.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2>{{html}}</h2>
    <span>{{greeting}}</span>
    <div ng-bind-html="editorHtml"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

var data = "\r\n\r\n<div id=\"myEditor\" name=\"myEditor\">\r\n\r\n\t\t<a href=\"http://example.com\">hi html</a>\r\n\t</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\t";
var script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('hi script');\r\n\r\n\t</" + "script>\r\n\t";

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$sce', '$scope' , function($sce, $scope) {
  $scope.html = data + script;
  $scope.editorHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery for this to work. Also don't forget ngSanitize.

```
Plunker
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zEXXCB459Tp25VJiyyZb?p=preview