# ngSanitize is not working using angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have modal window where i have data from parent controller I also have search feature in modal but when i open modal its not rendering the data into modal view i see object printing in console but its not binding to html. 
I have pasted error below , Any idea what is implemented wrong here ?

searchModal.html

```
<div class="row search-input-margin">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="search">Search Logs:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" ng-model="vm.searchLog">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="searchLogsText">
         <li  ng-repeat="item in data  | filter:vm.searchLog track by $index" ng-bind-html="item | highlight:vm.searchLog"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

searcCtrl.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').controller('SearchController',function ($scope,$rootScope,$uibModalInstance,searchFactory) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
    $scope.vm ={
        searchLog:'',
        searchLength:0,
        searchResults: []

    };
    $scope.data = angular.copy(searchFactory.getDitLogs());
    console.log(searchFactory.getDitLogs());
});
```

Error:

> Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Comment: Looks like your `item` isn't a string(/html), but an object. So your `searchFactory.getDitLogs()` probably returns an array of objects. Maybe you meant something like `ng-bind-html="item.someHtmlProperty"`

Comment: Code of "searchFactory.getDitLogs" function would be helpful, create a simple sample of what does this function return?

Comment: its just getter and setter factory, so i am setting data from parent and getting in modal. Console is printing the data

Comment: Doesn't look like you've added ngSanitize as a dependency ... angular.module('loggingApp', ['ngSanitize']) ...

Comment: ngSanitize is added i did not added app.js to question but it dependency is there

Comment: Simplified code is working - https://jsfiddle.net/pqw9ee2q/ the problem like @devqon said probably is lying in the return data from your function getDitLogs() - it must return an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need add [ngSanitize](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js) as a dependency and you should call $sce.trustAsHtml function ; when you want to use a string as html.

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

  myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$sce', '$scope' , function($sce, $scope) {
      var html = '<div>Hello Html!</div>'; 
      $scope.editorHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);

    }]);
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yshadmehr/rjyhe4h7/) or for more detail look at my aswser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646449/sce-trustashtml-is-not-evaluating-a-javascript-string-or-trustasjs-for-that-ma/41646768#41646768)

Comment: The $sce dependency is not needed, also no need to use trustAsHtml

Comment: How can I do that? Could you do that with [my js fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yshadmehr/rjyhe4h7/)?

Comment: What do you mean "YES"!  My Script does not work anymore!!! Run both samples to see different.